# Sort Excel table based on date in text with time stamp and time zone

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have an excel sheet column with date time and time zone.(31-JAN-2017 23:45 EST).

I tried converting it to date and sort it in excel but is not working.
It is considering it as text and Feb is coming before Jan.

Any idea how to do it.

I have tried converting it to custom format with date and time and still it is not working.

Comment: How have you tried to accomplish this "converting to date"?  What happened when you did that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new column with :

```
=DATEVALUE(YourCell)
```

or

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(YourCell,11))
```

And this will be a date that should be able to sort properly on! ;)

Comment: @TomSharpe : thx for pointing it out, I'm always mixing those translations! ;)